# Why does a rooster crow, but a crow caws?

Tags: etymology

Shouldn't a crow do crow, but why does it a rooster instead? The similar issue is in German language.

Comment: Ask the rooster and the crow.

Comment: They are two quite different sounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two terms are both of imitative origin, crow appears to be older in usage and probably for that reason first applied to a common, domestic animal.

***[Cockcrow](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cockcrow?s=ts)*** dates back to the  1350-1400 period;( Middle English), from Old English [crawe](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=crow&allowed_in_frame=0), imitative of bird's cry.

***[Caw](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/caw?s=t)*** was first recorded in 1580-90; of imitative origin.

(Dictionary.com) (Etymonlne)

Comment: The imitative quality is also called _onomatopoeia._ It is more likely that the bird's call (rather than the bird's name) is named after what we hear, and that varies in different languages. English hears laughter as _HaHa_; Hebrew as _KhaKha_.

Comment: Yes, it appears crawe is older than caw and initially includes all sounds of all such birds, but just survived for the cock while crows got a new word for what they do.